# Implementacion de patron observer con MVC

Tags: java

Tengo un problema a la hora de implementar el patròn observer a mi desarrollo. Es para calcular la nomina de un empleado (la clase padre es abstracta y es la observada), hay dos tipos de empleados uno de ventas y otro de honorarios en los cuales tengo implementado el metodo calcular nomina. La finalidad del programa es que sea observado si el empleado tiene algùn prestamo, el cual es descontado de la nomina y este valor final es el que deberìa ser observado. El problema es que no "observa" si tiene prestamo o no.

Les agradezco cualquier sugerencia

```
public abstract class Empleado extends Observable {


    protected String nombre;
    protected long prestamos;

    public abstract void calcular_nomina_total();

}

public class Empleado_Ventas extends Empleado {
    private int comision;
    private long salario_basico;
    private long venta;

    @Override
    public void calcular_nomina_total() {

        long comision = (this.venta * this.comision) / 100;
        long nomina = this.salario_basico + comision;
        long total = nomina - this.prestamos;
        if (this.prestamos > 0) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(total);
        }
    }

public class Empleado_honorarios extends Empleado {
    private int horas;
    private long valor_hora;

    @Override
    public void calcular_nomina_total() {
        long nomina = this.valor_hora * this.horas;
        long total = nomina - this.prestamos;
        if (this.prestamos > 0) { // si no tiene prestamos no debo notificar nada
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(total);
        }
    }
}

public class Control implements ActionListener {
    // Empleado objeto_empleado_observable = new Empleado(); NO PUEDO LLAMAR A LA
    // CLASE PADRE
    Empleado_Ventas objeto_empleado_ventas = new Empleado_Ventas();
    Empleado_honorarios objeto_empleado_honorarios = new Empleado_honorarios();
    Formulario_observer_desprendible objeto_formulario_obs1 = new Formulario_observer_desprendible();
    Banco_observador objeto_banco_obs2 = new Banco_observador();

    public Control(){
        objeto_formulario_obs1.getBtn_Calcular().addActionListener(this);
        objeto_empleado_ventas.addObserver(objeto_formulario_obs1);
        objeto_empleado_ventas.addObserver(objeto_banco_obs2);
        objeto_empleado_honorarios.addObserver(objeto_formulario_obs1);        
        objeto_empleado_honorarios.addObserver(objeto_banco_obs2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == objeto_formulario_obs1.getBtn_Calcular()){
            switch(objeto_formulario_obs1.getCmbx_Tipo_e().getSelectedIndex()){
                case 0: Empleado_honorarios objeto_empleado_honorarios = new Empleado_honorarios();
                objeto_empleado_honorarios.setNombre(objeto_formulario_obs1.getTxt_Nombre().getText());
                objeto_empleado_honorarios.setHoras(Integer.parseInt(objeto_formulario_obs1.getTxt_Hora_Porcentaje().getText()));
                objeto_empleado_honorarios.setValor_hora(Integer.parseInt(objeto_formulario_obs1.getTxt_Valorh_Salariob().getText()));
                objeto_empleado_honorarios.setPrestamos(Long.parseLong(objeto_formulario_obs1.getTxt_Prestamos().getText()));
                objeto_empleado_honorarios.calcular_nomina_total(); //debo calcularle la nomina asi no tenga prestamos

        }
```

EDITO: Clase observadora

```
public class Banco_observador implements Observer {

//este observador lo unico que debe hacer es mostrar el valor de la nomina al restarle el prestamo 

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.printlin(arg);
    }
}
```

EDITO CORRECCIÓN PARA EL QUE LE SIRVA... ya me funciona, tenia una serie de errores en la validación en el método

```
     public long calcular_nomina_total() 
    { //metodo de empleado ventas

     long comisiones,nomina;   
     if (this.prestamos > 0)
     {  
     comisiones= (this.venta*this.comision)/100; 
     nomina = this.salario_basico + comisiones;
     this.salario= nomina - this.prestamos;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(this.salario);
     return this.salario;
     }
     else
         return 0;

     }


public long calcular_nomina_total() 
    {
     //metodo de empleado honorarios
     long nomina;   
     if (this.prestamos > 0)
     {  
     nomina= this.valor_hora*this.horas;
     this.salario= nomina - this.prestamos;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(this.salario);
     return this.salario;
     }
     else
         return 0;

     }
```

Luego en el control coloco otro boton, uno inserta y el otro calcula y agrego las dos opciones de empleado sea checklist o lista despleglable para que los escuche el action listener.

Comment: Muestra un poco de código de los observers, al menos uno.

Comment: ya lo edite, aunque no tiene ciencia,lo unico que hace o deberia hacer el recibir el valor que le entrega el metodo calcularnomina() y listo.

Comment: ¿cual sería la pregunta? Yo lo que veo es que cada vez que calculas la nómina de un empleado le avisa al banco. Yo creo que el banco requiere saber cuando la pagas, y no cuando la calculas.

Comment: Lo que se le debe notificar al banco es si de la nomina se le quito el prestamo, es decir si ya esta a paz y salvo con el banco, es por ello que requiero notificarle cuanto le pago, sin embargo no muestra nada  y no se por qué  :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
     public long calcular_nomina_total() 
    { //metodo de empleado ventas

     long comisiones,nomina;   
     if (this.prestamos > 0)
     {  
     comisiones= (this.venta*this.comision)/100; 
     nomina = this.salario_basico + comisiones;
     this.salario= nomina - this.prestamos;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(this.salario);
     return this.salario;
     }
     else
         return 0;

     }


public long calcular_nomina_total() 
    {
     //metodo de empleado honorarios
     long nomina;   
     if (this.prestamos > 0)
     {  
     nomina= this.valor_hora*this.horas;
     this.salario= nomina - this.prestamos;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(this.salario);
     return this.salario;
     }
     else
         return 0;

     }
```

Comment: Por favor, explica cuál era el problema y cómo lograste resolverlo pues, en general, las respuestas que tienen solo código son consideradas de baja calidad. Un saludo.